Flutter command not found after manual installation on Ubuntu 24
I've successfully installed Flutter on Ubuntu 24 and created a Flutter project. However, when I try to run Flutter commands like flutter doctor, I get the following output:
Command 'flutter' not found, but can be installed with: sudo snap install flutter
Additional Information:

Flutter version: flutter_linux_3.22.3-stable
Ubuntu version: 24.04
Ubuntu installation: SSD drive
Flutter installation: HDD drive


before running flutter doctor, run the command "flutter", and check "flutter --version"

@MoonPrincess none of them works

Ok, till bin path has to added in environment variable, "/flutter/bin" then check
